# ASP.NET MVC website performance issue on Azure AppServices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, azure

We have a ASP.NET MVC5 website hosted on Azure AppServices.

We have 2 distinct instances of this site on Azure: 1 for tests and 1 for production.

This 2 instances are in distinct Azure plans, but all services considered in each instance is in the same region (Western Europe).

The first one seems to work in an acceptable manner, but we are facing performance issues loading some pages on the 2nd one (sometimes from 15s to +30s page load times).

Each of our application instance is composed of:

- ASP.NET MVC 5 (with FormsAuthentication)
- N-Tiers Architecture
- EntityFramework 6.1.3
- ApplicationInsights service
- 2 SqlServer Databases (1 for business data & 1 for security data) located in a Azure Sql Service

The Azure plan used is "Basic (Small)" for AppServices, and "S0 Standard (10 DTUs)" for SqlServices.
The 1st one is running around 5% for CPU and 58% for Memory. The 2nd one is running around 3% for DTU.

With AppInsights, I've seen that "all is ok in controller" and the problem might comes from below. 
I've also detected some page loads having the issue presents a failed Sql dependency call (with result code 207).

The Sql requests respond times are also separately ok (under 300ms).

We have, of course, already read a lot of posts about Azure performance issues but nothing that has helped us.

We would really appreciate some help please.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Enable the profiler in Application Insights (same thing that used to live under https://azureserviceprofiler.com). It's now under the **Performance** blade.

Stress test your application for a few hours, enough for a good amount of ETL traces to be collected so it can paint a comprehensive picture of where time is being spent. A tiny "trace" icon will then become available next to your controllers:

[image: Profiler]

Results look like this:

[image: traces]

Comment: Hi @evilSnobu ,
thanks for your quick answer.
I had not seen this tool yet in Azure, which is actually very useful.
But after 24hours of use, only 3 operations with around 300ms of response times present the "trace icon" as you said. SSo I can not use this information for the moment.
Do you know how to "force" this profiler to collect ETL of particular operations? (or why, in my case, only this 3 pages have the icon and not other operations which have shown catastrophic response times since the profiler has been activated ?)

Comment: That's a question for the App Insights Product Group. Try opening an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/issues, and/or placing a comment here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-profiler. Or even better, open a support case from the Azure Portal and provide them a link back to this question.

Comment: Yes, we have already submitted a support request to Microsoft about our issue.
Thanks again for your help